# How to setup reverse proxy for Apache and Jetty host with non root context path

Tags: apache, jenkins, proxy, jetty, reverse-proxy

I need to setup Apache 2.4 as a reverse proxy to Jetty 9 backend server so I will have the public site:
**https://jenkins.mysite.com** 
and it will be proxied to the internal
**http://localhost:8080/jenkins**

I tried different settings as well as:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>


    ServerName jenkins.mysite.com
    DocumentRoot /home/jenkins/web

    Alias / /home/jenkins/web/
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>


    SSLEngine on
    SSLProxyEngine On

    BrowserMatch    "MSIE [2-6]" nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0

    BrowserMatch "MSIE [17-9]" ssl-unclean-shutdown

    <Directory "/home/jenkins/web/WEB-INF/">
             AllowOverride None
             Require all denied
    </Directory>

    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyVia Off

    #Tried On and Off. With ProxyPassReverse and without
    ProxyPreserveHost Off

    #Tried all below settings with no luck
    #AllowEncodedSlashes NoDecode
    #RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https" env=HTTPS
    #RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Port 443

    <Proxy *>
      AddDefaultCharset off
          AllowOverride None
          Require all granted
    </Proxy>

    #Tried below instead of nocanon in ProxyPass
    #RewriteEngine on
    #RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    #RewriteRule .* http://127.0.0.1:8080/jenkins/%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,P,QSA]

    ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/jenkins nocanon 
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/jenkins

    #That was useful to remove contextPath from Cookie path
    #ProxyPassReverseCookiePath  "/jenkins"  "/"

    <Location />
       Options FollowSymLinks
       AddDefaultCharset off
       AllowOverride None
       Require all granted
     </Location>

    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/jenkins.mysite.com/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/jenkins.mysite.com/privkey.pem
        Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

For Jetty I tried to use **http-forwarded** module. It was not helpful with it or without it.

The best I could achieve that direct links worked. But all referenced urls and redirects(like login one) had the extra internal contextPath: /jenkins/*

Is there any way to setup it as I wish? Particularly to avoid complaints from the Jenkins that reverse proxy is broken?

I can make it work if I use the virtual host for jetty context with contextPath=/. But it requires to change the /etc/hosts which I'm trying to avoid.

Of course mysite.com is hypothetic name. I used some real domain name.
Thank you.

Comment: Why does [setting jetty context to /](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/configuring-contexts.html#setting-context-path) require any changes to `/etc/hosts`?

Comment: to make virtual hosts names. you have multiple vhosts with / context on one localhost.

Comment: Make sure your "Manage Jenkins" > "Configure System" > "Jenkins URL" is using the public URL that points to this proxy.

Comment: it was unchanged and should be the same. Definitely should not be a reason.